# Why does Netty 4.0.x have a default WebSocket frame size of only 65536 byte

Tags: java, security, websocket, netty

In Netty 4.0.x the default frame size for the [WebSocketServerProtocolHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.html#81) is 65536 byte but you can set it as high as you want. The WebSocket protocol limits the size to [18,446,744,073,709,551,615 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652194/websocket-frame-size-limitation#answer-20658569). Is there a reason for that low frame size? Are [DDOS-Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249478/how-to-limit-in-netty-length-of-websocket-frame-received-by-server) a reason for that behavior?

My Netty stack is as follows:

```
HttpServerCodec  
HttpContentCompressor  
HttpContentDecompressor  
HttpObjectAggregator(65536)  
WebSocketServerProtocolHandler(...,65536)  
...
```

Should I rather set the HttpObjectAggregator size to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 to avoid the TooLongFrameException and leave the WebSocketServerProtocolHandler to 65536? What is best practice?

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with Netty, but I would assume that is done to prevent overconsumption of memory (and in a way to prevent a [self-]DOS attack). If you need more, I would try to increase it only on the websockets that require a bigger frame size.

Comment: the problem is that you cannot configure browsers to use continuation frames at a certain fame size. something like auto-chunking is not possible. You need to extend you business logic to handle that. Why such a small limit? 64k is nothing. Imagine you want to upload an image.

Comment: websockets werent made for actual data transfer - clearly, they were intended for messaging / signalling systems. If you're transferring actual data via websocket you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @RichardBurkhardt Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. You state that the *default* is 65535, not the maximum, and you present zero evidence that Netty doesn't allow a larger size.

Comment: @EJP Thank you, I changed the question. Now it should be clear that you can actually set the size to what ever size you want.